# When $\min_{x \in X,y \in Y} f(x,y) = \min_{x \in X} \min_{y \in Y} f(x,y)$?

Tags: optimization, convex-optimization, numerical-optimization, discrete-optimization

When $$ \min_{x \in X,y \in Y} f(x,y) = \min_{x \in X} \min_{y \in Y} f(x,y) \qquad? $$ 
I mean when we are minimizing a function with respect to two variables, under what conditions we are allowed to minimize over one variable and then minimize over the other one?

Comment: when you do your first minimization (the inner one on $y$), you implicitly assume that you can compare functions (the functions $x\mapsto f(x,y)$) . What order do you use on functions?

Comment: Thank you! what do you mean by order?

Comment: I mean what is the meaning of $\min_y f(x,y)$? The only meaning I see would be the minimum of all functions $f(\cdot,y)$, but then you need to define what is the minimum operation for functions.

Comment: To take an example, let's say $f(x,y)=\sin(x)+\sin(y)$, what is the result of $\min_x \min_y f(x,y)$ ?

Comment: obviously, it's $\min_x \sin(x) + \min_y \sin(y)$

Comment: when you say "under what conditions we are allowed to minimize over one variable and then minimize over the other one?", I don't understand what your first step is. How can you minimize a two-variable function on only one variable? Do you see the problem?

Comment: In your example we are allowed to do so. I'm looking for a general condition that we are allowed to do so.

Comment: if you compare functions via their minimum values (which you are probably doing without noticing), then $\min_{x,y}$ is exactly the same as $\min_x\min_y$. If you claim it's not always the same, can you give an example?

Comment: $x$ and $y$ are not necessarily are possible real numbers. Let me edit the question!

Comment: so you mean we are always allowed to do minimization separately?

Comment: Again, you didn't define precisely what it means to do it separately. But in the only way that makes sense, yes you always can, and the order does not matter.

Comment: Would you mind looking at [this link](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/438127/why-these-two-problems-lead-to-same-answers)? All I want to do is that. Thanks

Comment: in the link you have $\min$ and $\max$, which cannot be reverted in general. You ask about $\min$ and $\min$, that always can.

Comment: Thank you. You know if we separate the minimization, the argmin of the inner minimization ($y^*$) would be function of the outer minimzation parameter ($x$). When the inner minimizer is independent of the outer minimization parameter. For my case when $y^*$ is independent of parameter $x$?

Comment: I don't understand your question...

Comment: Assume we are going to minimize $xy+y^2$. First minimizing over $y$ gives $y^*=-x \over 2$ and we must put this $y^*$ in $g(x)=f(x,y^*)$ and minimize over $x$. I'm looking for a condition that the solution $y^*$ is not a function of $x$. Thanks

Comment: I don't agree with your $y^*$, for instance with $x=-10$, choosing $y=1$ is better than $y=5$.

Comment: $y=1$ leads to $-9$ and $y=5$ leads to $-25$ and obviously the latter is better.

Comment: oups yes sorry, I thought you were aiming at $0$, went too fast.
So for the independence of $y^*$ in $x$, the easy case is when $x$ do not appear in the derivative of $f(x,y)$ with respect to $y$. So  $f(x,y)$ is of the form $g(x)+h(y)$.
It could only be that $x$ do appear in the formula, but not in the solution for the minimum, for instance for $f(x,y)=x^2y^2$. This case can probably be detected by showing that the $y$-derivative $2x^2 y$ is of the form $h(x)g(y)$, so $x$ does not influence its roots.

Comment: Thank you for your kind answers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I compile the answer here for clarity.

First I reformulate the question : 
given a function of two variables $f(x,y)$, its minimum can be written $\min_x y^*(x)$, where $y^*(x)=\min_y f(x,y)$.
Question: under which condition $y^*(x)$ is a constant function, so is independent of $x$?

Answer:
Let $f'(x,y)$ be the $y$-derivative of $f(x,y)$.
$y^*(x)$ is exprimable as a solution of $f'(x,y)=0$.
A sufficient condition for $y^*$ to be a constant is if $f'(x,y)$ is of the form $h(x,y)g(y)$, where $y^*$ is a root of $g$.

I don't know about a proof of the converse, but this should cover most cases in practice...

Answer (score 5):

For each $x$,
$$
\min_yf(x,y)\ge\min_{x,y}f(x,y)\tag{1}
$$
Taking the minimum over $x$,
$$
\min_x\min_yf(x,y)\ge\min_{x,y}f(x,y)\tag{2}
$$
However, there is an $(x_0,y_0)$ so that $f(x_0,y_0)=\min\limits_{x,y}f(x,y)$. Then
$$
\min_yf(x_0,y)=\min_{x,y}f(x,y)\tag{3}
$$
Therefore, we must have that the minimum over all $x$ is at most the value at one $x_0$:
$$
\min_x\min_yf(x,y)\le\min_{x,y}f(x,y)\tag{4}
$$
$(2)$ and $(4)$ show that
$$
\min_x\min_yf(x,y)=\min_{x,y}f(x,y)\tag{5}
$$