# Prove that $\min_{x,y} f(x,y) = \min_{x}(\min_{y}f(x,y))$

Tags: optimization

> Given $f\colon X \times Y \to \mathbb{R}$, prove that
> \begin{align*}
> \min_{(x,y) \in X \times Y} f(x,y) = \min_{x \in X}\left( \min_{y \in Y} f(x,y) \right).
> \end{align*}

Intuitively, I see that the left hand side is the minimum value over all possible pairs $(x,y)$ in $X \times Y$. Say that the minimiser is $(x^o,y^o)$.

For the right hand side, we pick $x = x_1$, then find a $y=y_1$ which minimises $f(x_1,y)$, then repeat this process for all $x \in X$. Now in this process when $x = x^o$, $y$ will take value $y^o$, since that is the minimum value the function can take for any possible pair. Hence they equality seems true.

How do I show this rigorously?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [When $\min_{x \in X,y \in Y} f(x,y) = \min_{x \in X} \min_{y \in Y} f(x,y)$?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/438269/when-min-x-in-x-y-in-y-fx-y-min-x-in-x-min-y-in-y-fx-y)

Comment: This is duplicated! Please check the above comment